# Memory Issue when Play & Stop Audio file multiple times

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-mediaplayer

I'm writing an game where need to play multiple sound file multiple times.

I'm using MediaPlayer object to relocate file and play each time when needed. Following code I'm using :

```
try {
            if (commonPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                commonPlayer.stop();
                commonPlayer.release();
            }

            commonPlayer = null;

            switch (gameAction) {
                case 1:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tap);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.score);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.die);
                    break;
            }

            commonPlayer.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

But after play multiple times it stop playing with following error:

```
01-24 22:25:51.215   263 28967 I ACodec  : codec does not support config priority (err -2147483648)
01-24 22:25:51.216   263 28967 I MediaCodec: MediaCodec will operate in async mode
01-24 22:25:51.219 22703 22703 I Score   : 3, 15
01-24 22:25:51.220   263 28965 E AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131176
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28965 D MemoryDealer:   AudioTrack (0xa15abbd0, size=4194304)
.......
0x00260980 | 0x00020080 | A 
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28965 D MemoryDealer:    
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28965 E AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28965 E AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28965 E AudioSink: Unable to create audio track
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28965 W NuPlayerRenderer: openAudioSink: non offloaded open failed status: -19
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28962 E NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffed) from audio decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28962 D NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xab839b00), (100, 1, -19)
01-24 22:25:51.221 22703 22773 E MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
01-24 22:25:51.221   263 28965 W NuPlayerRenderer: onDrainAudioQueue(): audio sink is not ready
```

Any suggestion about how to play sound file multiple times ?

Answer (score 1):

**instead of this**

```
try {
            if (commonPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                commonPlayer.stop();
                commonPlayer.release();
            }

            commonPlayer = null;

            switch (gameAction) {
                case 1:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tap);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.score);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.die);
                    break;
            }

            commonPlayer.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

**try this**

```
commonPlayer = null;

            switch (gameAction) {
                case 1:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.tap);

          commonPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());

                    break;

                case 2:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.score);
commonPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());

                    break;

                case 3:
                    commonPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.die);
commonPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());

                    break;
            }

            commonPlayer.start();

        } 

 private class musicCompletionListener implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        commonPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: In observation I found this could lead NLP in media listener & with null check story will be same I guess. What I really found keep **commonPlayer.release();** from isPlaying check. This helped me.

Comment: does the above answer solve your porblem? if so please accept the answer :) or else let me know for any modification needed ..

Comment: I added issue with your answer. Also added what can be done & this is what working for me.

Comment: glad to help. can you accept the answer?. and close this question :) ?